# Recursively grouping children values with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I work with some complex data objects and I need to map some data from children to parents dynamically, recursively till the top level. Leaving details aside, I'm stack at the following operation. between the lowest level children and their immediate parents, which will then be recursively applied to the parents: given an array of children's data...

```
 [ 
   [
     ['key 1', 1],
     ['key 2', null],
     ['key 3', 42]
   ],
   [
     ['key 1', null],
     ['key 2', 42],
     ['key 3', 0]
   ],
   [
     ['key 1', 21],
     ['key 2', 21],
     ['key 3', 21]
   ],
 ]
```

... I'm trying to get the parent data to look like this:

```
[
  [
    'key 1', [1, null, 21]
  ],
  [
    'key 2', [null, 42, 21]
  ],
  [
    'key 3', [42, 0, 21]
  ]
]
```

Most likely, I could achieve this using good'ol `for`s, but I'm pretty sure there's a slick way of doing it with `_.groupBy`, `_.chain` or `_.thru`. I'm still struggling with `_`.

It kind of feels like giving up, asking here, but I've been at this for over a day, trying to find anything similar and reading through lodash's *Array* and *Collection* functions without any result.

If you want to test it on a jsFiddle, I've extracted a small piece of live data for tests in this [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/c5t5o8j1/).

Comment: Demo data doesn't resemble question data, not clear what expected results are there

Comment: The question data is a simplified version of the `data` variable in the fiddle, the one I'm logging to console, @charlietfl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten, then group by the 1st index, and map the groups to the expected result.

```js
var data = [[["key 1",1],["key 2",null],["key 3",42]],[["key 1",null],["key 2",42],["key 3",0]],[["key 1",21],["key 2",21],["key 3",21]]];

var result = _(data)
  .flatten()
  .groupBy(_.head)
  .map(function(v, k) {
    return [k, _.map(v, _.last)];
  })
  .value();
 
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I feel so silly. I tried this but instead of grouping by `[0]`, I grouped by `0` and also used `1` instead of `[1]`. Now that I look at it I don't know what I was thinking. Thank you so much.

Comment: Aside for Andrei Gheorghiu: Instead of using [0] and [1] you could use `_.head` and `_.last` respectively e.g. `.groupBy(_.head)`.

Comment: @GruffBunny - good idea. It's more readable then using index strings.

Comment: @GruffBunny, I should ask `_.` questions more often. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla js:

```js
let data = [[["key 1",1],["key 2",null],["key 3",42]],[["key 1",null],["key 2",42],["key 3",0]],[["key 1",21],["key 2",21],["key 3",21]]];

let tmp =data
  // flatten subarrays
  .reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), [])
  // create object using 1st index value as keys, array as value
  .reduce((a, c) => { 
    a[c[0]] = a[c[0]] || [c[0],[]];
    a[c[0]][1].push(c[1]);
    return a
  }, {});
// get all the arrays from object
let res = Object.values(tmp);

console.log(res);
```